# PCA vs t-SNE in asset pricing

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

So I am trying dimensionality reduction techniques on the S&P500 FY2020 data.

I understand the CAPM model and the fact that doing a PCA determines my market variability factor (the first PCA component).

What I am wondering is, what intuitions (if any) does t-SNE give on the same data? Using scikit-learn I have embeddings for the first component, but does the embedding relate to CAPM in any way? Or for that matter any other asset pricing model?

What I have tried,

1. PCA for 99% variance and computed projections for the first PC (PC1 weight times daily change of every stock's price, then summed across all stocks)
2. A 2D t-SNE on the same data
3. A 1D t-SNE on the same data

Below is a plot of the above 3.

[image]

Comment: How are you performing those ? on prices ? on returns ? in a lagged manner ?

Comment: So the data is organised into columns (one each for the 500 stocks) and then 393 rows (one each for a day). And I have prices for each stock each day, as data.

I am doing a transform on the price data to get to the daily price change for every stock as below,


```X = df_.apply(np.log).diff(1)``` 


where X is the daily change dataframe and df_ is the original dataframe with daily price data.


My df_.info() result,


```<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 393 entries, 0 to 392
Columns: 503 entries, A to ZTS
dtypes: float64(503)
memory usage: 1.5 MB```